# Table Join Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

If I had two separate tables set up like this:

```
University 1:

student   major   year    gpa


University 2:

student   major   address   gpa   hometown  extra curriculars
```

Is there a way I could get majors sorted by the top gpa in that major? Sorry, this is probably a simple question, I'm fairly new with Ruby on Rails though. Thanks!

Comment: i would like to answer this question, with a question: why is University 1 and University 2 need separate tables? seems like they should both be in a table called universities. then you could simply call University.select("DISTINCT gpa").order("gpa DESC")

Comment: This is more of an example. The two tables I'm actually working with can't be consolidated into one. Sorry, I should have made that more clear in the post.

Comment: Do you want the top GPA for each major in each university? E.g. if the top Math GPA in #1 is 3.9 and the top Math GPA in #2 is 3.5, do you want your result set to include "Math, 3.9" only, or that as well as "Math, 3.5"?

Comment: I want the set to include only "Math 3.9".

Comment: Looking at the issues list for Arel on github, it sounds like Arel will support unions eventually, but doesn't now. If that's the case, I think you might be stuck with find_by_sql and something like my query below in order to get a maximum between the two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the top GPA by major across the two universities, the SQL looks like this, for example:

```
SELECT major, MAX(GPA) AS GPA FROM
  (SELECT major, MAX(GPA) AS GPA FROM UNIVERSITY_1
   GROUP BY major
   UNION
   SELECT major, MAX(GPA) AS GPA FROM UNIVERSITY_2
   GROUP BY major)
GROUP BY major
ORDER BY GPA DESC
```

I'm not sure how to express that query in Arel - not sure how it does unions, and that would be good to know. In the meantime you can always use find_by_sql to get a result set from the raw SQL.

**EDIT:**

A somewhat Ruby-er/Railsier way to do it might be:

```
u_one = UniversityOne.maximum :gpa, :group => 'major'
u_two = UniversityTwo.maximum :gpa, :group => 'major'
u_combined = u_one.merge(u_two) { |k, one, two| [one,two].max }
```

`u_combined` ends up being a hash with the major as the key and the max gpa across universities as the value.

Comment: What variable would I call find_by_sql("SELECT major, MAX(GPA) AS GPA FROM
  (SELECT major, MAX(GPA) AS GPA FROM UNIVERSITY_1
   GROUP BY major
   UNION
   SELECT major, MAX(GPA) AS GPA FROM UNIVERSITY_2
   GROUP BY major)
GROUP BY major
ORDER BY GPA DESC") on to get it to work? University1?

Comment: Either model class should work, e.g. UniversityOne.find_by_sql(...) or UniversityTwo.find_by_sql(...).

Answer (score 0):

This is something SQL does well, so you could do it in SQL.  (Doing this in ruby code after to get the results is clear enough that you should be able to figure it out.)

```
SELECT *
FROM university
GROUP BY major
ORDER BY MAX(gpa) DESC
```

So, in Rails 2.x

```
University.find(:group => "major", :order => "MAX(gpa) DESC")
```

In Rails 3.0

```
University.group("major").order("MAX(gpa) DESC")
```

Comment: This works if you want to get separate lists for each table, except that the `SELECT *` will blow up because you aren't grouping by the fields in the SELECT clause, and you never had MAX(GPA) in the SELECT clause, so you can't order by it. Instead I think you'd want:

   `SELECT MAJOR, MAX(GPA)
    FROM university
    GROUP BY MAJOR
    ORDER BY MAX(GPA)`

That said I think the ActiveRecord code gets you there.

Comment: Yeah, when I learned the rules, you could only order by fields in the select.  But DBs also made you have all the non-aggregated fields in the order by, and other rules have changed.